# Startup Disk Full: Core File

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, startup, core-storage

The storage on my start up disk is being consumed by some kind of core files labeled as cores:1234 (numerical digits change). I downloaded OmniSweeper, which helped me locate these files and aware that each one is the size of >300mb. How do I disable this?

It is taking up space by the minute, literally. Screen shot provided below.

Thanks, 
DG

[image]

Comment: Open terminal and run `sudo fs_usage -w | grep core` to see what program is responsible for creating these. Otherwise, you'll need to look in to them and see what the details of the core. They are error and crash reports, so you might be able to delete one program or one setting to cure what ails this mac.

Comment: It sounds like a malfunctioning application is dumping it's entire core, which is standard for debugging purposes, especially for Java-based applications.  Core dumps can be enormous in size and are absolutely safe to delete.  However, as @bmike noted, you should probably find the program responsible for creating them in the first place if you want to prevent this from happening in the future.

Answer (score 1):

They are coredumps, they are the result of a unix program crashing and then getting it's core dumped, which is basically a file containg what the program was doing when it crashed (memory state and CPU state).

If you have that many, it might be a symptom of a bigger underlying cause which you can check by inspecting the logs of you system using the Console app. To find out what binary (application program) the core belongs to, you can use the Terminal:

1. Open Terminal.app
2. Type "file " (excluding the quotes but keeping the space at the end)
3. Drop a core file on the terminal window, and it's full path will be entered
4. Press enter and the response will tell you all readable details on the file

In the end, however, unless you are a software developer, there is no point in keeping those core dump files, you can simply delete all of them.